# Pass multiple parameters to gesture recogniser

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a UITableView.
Each cell has got a series of UIImageViews, and their urls are saved into an array.
When I tap on a certain image, the selector for my gesture recogniser should get both the tag of the image and the `indexPath.row` of the cell.

I'm currently getting the image tag from the `sender` parameters, and this is the way in which I'm trying to get the indexpath:

```
let point = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
let indexPathRow = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)?.row
```

However, this looks like it's not giving me the right row.
Is there an easy way to pass these two parameters to my gesture selector? Thanks.

Comment: Pass them in a collectiontype (Array, Dictionary, Set)

Comment: yes but how.. the only parameters I'm successfully passing are the ones tied to the sender. @Arbitur

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question, Ill post an answer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass the gesture recogniser you're using and add the extra variables you want. Example below.

```
class CustomGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer {

    var url : NSURL?
    // any more custom variables here

    init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector, url : NSURL) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)

        self.url = url
    }

}
```

Then when you want to get the url back out.

```
func didTap(sender : CustomGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I believe is to subclass the UIImageView to hold your NSIndexPath:

```
class MyImageView: UIImageView {
    var indexpath:NSIndexPath!
}
```

And then to get that indexPath:

```
func tap(tap: UITapgestureRecognizer) {
    let imgView = tap.view as! MyImageView
    let indexPath = imgView.indexPath
    let tag = imgView.tag
}
```